# Getting unable to parse date exception

Tags: java, date, date-format

I have date and time on string type `20/03/2018, 18:20:44` Is it possible to change it to date format in java? I tried this code:

```
public static Date getDate(String dateString) {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    try {
        Date date = formatter.parse(dateString);
        return date;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error("error while parsing milliseconds to date" + dateString, e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I get unable to parse exception and returned with null

Comment: `dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss`

Comment: `mm` represents minutes not months. `MM` represents months

Comment: Exactly, refer to [SimpleDateFormat javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) section `Date and Time Patterns`

Comment: tried replacing 'mm' with 'MM' for months it still din't work

Comment: The error message, "error while parsing milliseconds to date", seems unrelated to the code here.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've used the wrong string replacements inside your simple date format, it should be `dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss`. Note the capitalisation of the HH as well, your time is in 24 hour format so it must be `HH` over `hh`

So with the applied changes your code will look like this:

```
public static Date getDate(String dateString) {
  DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss");
  formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
  try {
    return formatter.parse(dateString);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    logger.error("error while parsing milliseconds to date" + dateString, e);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Read more on the various patterns available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), as an aside it is generally recommended to use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format for dates, so yours would be `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 3):

You should use the same format with input string:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

You did two mistakes :

- `mm` represents minutes. `MM` represents months.
  But You specify `mm` in the month part of the date format.
- the coma character : `,` provided  in the input has also to be present in the date format.

So with a String input in this form : `"20/03/2018, 18:20:44"`, you should use this DateFormat :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Your formatting pattern was incorrect, using the wrong case and omitting the comma.

Also, you are using troublesome classes supplanted years ago by *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDateTime.parse(                                       // Create a `LocalDateTime` object as the input string lacks any time zone or offset-from-UTC.
    "20/03/2018, 18:20:44" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu, HH:mm:ss" )  // Define a formatting pattern to match the input.
)
.atZone(                                                   // Assign a time zone to the `LocalDateTime` to create a `ZonedDateTime` object.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" )                     // Specify time zone to be assigned. Always use proper zone names `continent/region`; never use 3-4 character pseudo-zones.
)
```

> 2018-03-20T18:20:44-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

## java.time

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Parse your string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) since it lacks an indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

```
String input = "20/03/2018, 18:20:44" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu, HH:mm:ss" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-03-20T18:20:44

Lacking a time zone or offset-from-UTC means that this does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. Without the context of a zone/offset, this represents only a vague idea about potential moments along a range of 26-27 hours.

Apparently you are certain this input was actually meant to be in certain time zone. Apply a `ZoneId` to this `LocalDateTime` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

## Conversion

Best to avoid the troublesome legacy classes. But if you must produce a `java.util.Date` to inter-operate with old code not yet updated for *java.time*, you can convert. To convert back and forth, call new methods on the old classes.

A `java.util.Date` represents a point on the timeline in UTC, with a resolution of milliseconds. So its replacement in *java.time* is `Instant`. An `Instant` is also a point on the timeline in UTC, with a finer resolution of nanoseconds. To get to a `Date`, we need an `Instant`, which we can pull from our `ZonedDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

Now we can get the legacy class object, `Date`, by calling [`Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from(java.time.Instant)).

```
java.util.Date date = Date.from( instant ) ;  // Do this only if you *must* work with `Date` class.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Hm, although I see and understand that you are a big fan of new `java.time`-package, your recommendation of using it would unfortunately not have prevented the OP from using the wrong pattern. So the fact remains that `java.time` is still not clever enough to prevent such user mistakes (although certainly the better library compared with `SimpleDateFormat`). And as usual practice in most of your time-related posts, advertising an extra 3rd-party-libry  although completely unrelated to the concrete problem of the OP is at least to say superfluous.

Comment: One detail of my previous comment was imprecise. `java.time` would reject the pattern in parsing by throwing a runtime exception with a message which might not be very clear for many users. And for formatting/printing, `java.time` would not even complain about such an obviously wrong pattern!